# How can we define a 'periodic' parametric curve which is not closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

We all know that that the curve given by $\gamma (t)=(t,\sin t)$ has a repeated pattern, even though it's not a periodic curve. Can we generalize somehow the definition of a periodic curve so that curves like the one above are included?

When can we say that $\gamma (t)=(x(t), y(t))$ is 'periodic'? I found it good for $x'$ and $y$ to be periodic, with the same period. Is that the most general result that can be foud?

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without knowing exactly what you mean by "repeated pattern". We may say that $\gamma$ has a repeated pattern, if there exists $T$ a positive real number and $C$ a vector such that $\gamma(t+T)=\gamma(t)+C$ for any $t$ in the domain of $\gamma$.  Periodic $\gamma$ corresponds to $C=0$. $\gamma(t)=(t,\sin(t))$ corresponds to $T=2\pi$ and $C=(2\pi,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may say that a curve is "periodic with respect to a vector $v$" if the function $t \mapsto \langle \gamma (t), v \rangle$ is periodic. In your example, choose $v = (0, 1)$.

A periodic curve (in the usual sense), then, would be one with the following property: there exist $T$ (the principal period) such that for every $v$ there exist $n_v \in \mathbb N$ making the curve $\gamma$ periodic with respect to $v$ with period $n_v T$. (Just use the vectors of the basis to get that all the components are periodic.)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The example $t \mapsto (t, \sin t)$ falls under the umbrella of *equivariant mappings*, along the lines mentioned by Taladris.

To start with an overly-general definition: Let $G$ be a group, and let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces equipped with left actions of $G$. (Concretely, for each group element $g$, there is a homeomorphism $\phi_{g}:X \to X$, and $\phi_{gh} = \phi_{g} \circ \phi_{h}$ for all $g$ and $h$ in $G$. Particularly, $\phi_{e}$ is the identity map of $X$, and $\phi_{g^{-1}} = (\phi_{g})^{-1}$ for all $g$ in $G$. The space $Y$ is equipped similarly with homeomorphisms $\psi_{g}$.)

A continuous mapping $f:X \to Y$ is *equivariant* (with respect to the group actions) if $f \circ \phi_{g} = \psi_{g} \circ f$ for all $g$ in $G$, namely, if
$$
f\bigl(\phi_{g}(x)\bigr) = \psi_{g}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)
  \quad\text{for all $x$ in $X$ and all $g$ in $G$.}
\tag{1}
$$

- Let $G$ be the additive group of integers, $X = \Reals$ the Euclidean line, and $Y = \Reals^{n}$ for some $n \geq 1$. Fix a positive real number $\ell$. Let $G$ act on $X = \Reals$ through translation $\phi_{n}(x) = x + n\ell$, and on $Y = \Reals^{n}$ by the identity transformation. An equivariant mapping $f:\Reals \to \Reals^{n}$ is precisely an $\ell$-periodic mapping; condition (1) says $f(x + n\ell) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $\Reals$.
- If in the preceding item $G$ acts on $\Reals^{n}$ by translation $\psi_{n}(y) = y + n\bigl(f(\ell) - f(0)\bigr)$, then $f$ is equivariant if and only if
  $$
  \underbrace{f(x + n\ell)}_{(f \circ \phi_{n})(x)}
     = \underbrace{f(x) + n\bigl(f(\ell) - f(0)\bigr)}_{(\psi_{n} \circ f)(x)}
    \quad\text{for all real $x$.}
  \tag{2}
  $$
  The mapping $f:\Reals \to \Reals^{2}$ defined by $f(x) = (x, \sin x)$ satisfies (2) for $\ell = 2\pi$, since $f(2\pi) - f(0) = (2\pi, 0)$, and
  $$
  f(x + 2\pi n) = f(x) + (2\pi n, 0)\quad\text{for all real $x$.}
  $$
- The action on the target space $Y$ need not be through translation. Fix an integer $k \geq 2$. If the additive group of integers acts on $X = \Reals$ by translation through multiples of $\ell = 2\pi/k$ and acts on $Y = \Reals^{2}$ by rotations through multiples of $2\pi/k$, i.e., by $\psi_{n}(r, \theta) = (r, \theta + 2\pi n/k)$ in polar coordinates, then $f(x) = \cos(kx)(\cos x, \sin x)$ (which traces a [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28mathematics%29) curve) is equivariant:
  $$
  f(x + \ell) = \cos(kx)\bigl(\cos(x + \ell), \sin(x + \ell)\bigr)
  \quad\text{for all real $x$,}
  $$
  and the right-hand side is the result of rotating the plane through an angle $\ell = 2\pi/k$.
- Let $k > 1$ be a real number. If the additive group of integers acts on $X = \Reals$ through translation by multiples of $2\pi$ and acts of $Y = \Reals^{2}$ by radial scaling with factor $k$, i.e., $\psi_{n}(y_{1}, y_{2}) = k^{n}(y_{1}, y_{2})$, then the [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) $f(x) = k^{x/(2\pi)}(\cos x, \sin x)$ is equivariant:
  $$
  f(x + 2\pi) = k^{(x + 2\pi)/(2\pi)}\bigl(\cos(x + 2\pi), \sin(x + 2\pi)\bigr)
    = kf(x)\quad\text{for all real $x$.}
  $$
- The group $G$ need not be discrete. If $k$ is a real number, and if $G$ is the additive group of reals, acting on itself by translation $\phi_{t}(x) = x + t$, and acting on $Y = \Reals^{3}$ in cylindrical coordinates by
  $$
  \psi_{t}(r, \theta, z) = (r, \theta + t, z + kt),
  $$
  then the [circular helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) $f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x, kx)$ is equivariant. (This example is closely related to why threaded screws and bolts work. The threads "enforce" a particular group action of the preceding type. A screwdriver or wrench impels rotation about an axis, and the group action forces the fastener to undergo translational motion along its axis.)
- If $G$ is the multiplicative group $\{1, -1\}$, and if $X = Y = \Reals$, we may define a $G$-action $\phi = \psi$ on $X = Y$ by $\phi_{g}(x) = gx$. An equivariant function $f:\Reals \to \Reals$ is precisely an odd function, satisfying
  $$
  f(-x) = -f(x)\quad\text{for all real $x$.}
  $$
  If instead $G$ acts "trivially" on $Y$, i.e., by the identity, then an equivariant function is even. (At this point it should be noted how easy it is to [make the simplest idea complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Made_Difficult), or conversely, to point out that the most sophisticated mathematical notions grow from elementary roots.)

These examples barely scratch the surface of [equivariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map). (In each, the group $G$ is Abelian, and the domain and target are Euclidean spaces.)